# How to create a web page that reads a TIFF file, modifies pixels and provides the modified TIFF file?

Tags: javascript, html, tiff

How to create a web page that takes a TIFF file, modifies pixels and provides the modified TIFF file? Any metadata should be the preserved. The following code fails with "unknown tag type":

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Modify tiff</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="UTIF.js"></script>
    <input type="file" id="fileSelector", accept="image/tiff">
    <script>
      document.getElementById('fileSelector').onchange = event => {
        const tiffFile = event.target.files[0];
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = () => {
            const tiffData = reader.result;
            const ifds = UTIF.decode(tiffData);
            for (let page = 0; page < ifds.length; ++page) {
              UTIF.decodeImage(tiffData, ifds[page]);
              const w = ifds[page].width;
              const h = ifds[page].height;
              const imgData = UTIF.toRGBA8(ifds[page]);
              for (let i = 0; i < imgData.length; ++i) imgData[i] = (imgData[i] + 1) % 2;
              UTIF.encodeImage(imgData, w, h);
            }
            const newFile = new File([UTIF.encode(ifds)], 'modified.tif', { type : 'image/tiff' });
            const link = document.createElement('a');
            link.style.display = 'none';
            link.href = URL.createObjectURL(newFile);
            link.download = 'modified.tif';
            document.body.appendChild(link);
            link.click();
            link.remove();
          };
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(tiffFile);
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have something working with Python and numpy but I want to be able to do it on a computer without Python but with a browser. I am mostly interested in images with only binary pixels.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell you how to fix it as I'm no js expert; Nor a TIFF expert. What I do know is that the `UTIF.decodeImage` function that you're using in your for loop is adding new fields called `isLE`, `data`, `width` and `height` to your `ifds` object.

After the loop, you've called `UTIF.encode(ifds)` which in turn calls the [`UTIF._writeIFD`](https://github.com/photopea/UTIF.js/blob/45047db39bd6395b84b8c1690baefb01fba93019/UTIF.js#L1274) function where there's a loop iterating over the keys in `ifds` expecting them to be of tXYZ form where XYZ is a TIFF tag number, encountering `isLE` instead, which results in NaN when fed to `parseInt("isLE".slice(1))`, the same NaN you're seeing in the console when it throws an Error.

Is this a bug on your part or UTIF.js I know not (perhaps you should inform them if you're qualified to judge) but you can clone `ifds` before the loop and then pass the clone to `UTIF.encode` like so:

```
const ifdsClone = structuredClone(ifds);
for (;;) {
   // That loop
}
const newFile = new File([UTIF.encode(ifdsClone)], ...);
```

Or perhaps some other smarter js solution to not having those 4 fields in that objects.

I'm actually here to offer help regarding the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76946506/how-can-a-script-read-my-incoming-telegram-messages-and-reply-to-them-as-me) you had asked on SO but had it closed as offtopic and the answer above is only a bonus. I don't have enough reputation to comment on that question, so I thought what better way to tel you this other than answering another question of yours. I find it very appaling that SO community would rather break the bro code, just so to comply with the SO code. @SharpBritannia is my GitHub and Telegram handle; My pals and I shall honour the bro code there.

Comment: That other smarter js solution to not having those 4 fields in that object could be this:
['isLE', 'width', 'height', 'data'].forEach(x => delete ifds[page][x]);

Unfortunately, that seems to make the resluting file rather empty.